# Solving limit using ratio test

Tags: calculus, limits

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{(-1)^n-n}$ and I want to perform root test.

I need to calculate: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ so this is equal to

$\frac{2^{(-1)^{n+1}-(n+1)}}{2^{(-1)^{n}-n}}$

How I can simply this to that I can apply one of the ratio test statements?

Comment: $\frac{a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$

Comment: yup, but what to do with (-1)^--- @BernardMasse

Comment: In fact the series converges by comparison with $\sum 2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Now you use the fact that$$\frac{2^{(-1)^{n+1}-(n+1)}}{2^{(-1)^n-n}}=2^{(-1)^{n+1}-(-1)^n-1}=\begin{cases}2&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\\frac18&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Therefore, the ratio test is inconclusive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it'd better to apply Cauchy's root test here.
Let $a_n=2^{(-1)^n-n} $ clearly $a_n\geq 0$.
Now ,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \sqrt[n]{a_n}= \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-1} = 2^{-1} =\frac{1}{2} < 1 $$
Hence the series converges.

Comment: The reason being that d'Alemberts ratio test is inconclusive here. Also Cauchy's root test is much stronger than the ratio test because of Cauchy's second theorem on limits.